# Debug Slow Razor View

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have ASP MVC 4 web application.
One of the actions return very slowly. I use MiniProfiler to profile the application.

We handle the duration of the action itself which is now 14ms, the problem is that there is still about 1.5s on the step of the request itself, without the time of the action on the controller (please see the attached image).

[image: MiniProfiler screen shoot]

As you can see the first line duration (1262.3) is the duration **without** the children.
As far as I understand this is the time of the razor engine rending.
It is important to note the slowness persist, it is not just the first request. It never goes bellow 800ms and sometime up-to 2s.

How can I profile the rendering itself?
The view is quite complex with several partial views in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if Glimpse gives you more insight

http://getglimpse.com/

Rendering a View can take very long if Routes are calculated. Check how long rendering takes if you remove all ActionLinks and similiar Html Helpers.

Comment: We have tons of ActionLinks, I'll give it a try

Comment: Also make sure that you are not compiling for debug (eg in your web.config  <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" /> ) If you are in debug mode MVC will not do any view lookup caching (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/marcinon/2011/08/16/optimizing-asp-net-mvc-view-lookup-performance/) - one of my pages went from a 18s render time to 1s, which is a huge difference

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a SQL query is being executed in your view. This could happen if you are using some ORM framework such as EntityFramework which is lazily loading entities and they are eagerly fetched from the database once you *touch* at their properties (which happens in your view). I I would recommend you using view models and eagerly loading everything in the controller action instead of waiting this to happen in your view.

Comment: Try switching to Release mode. In Release mode view locations are cached. If you have gazillions of partial views being included, this might be the cause.

Comment: "In Release mode view locations are cached." Was this documented somewhere, or did you find this out via, e.g. .NET Reflector? This is the type of behind the scenes detail I like to find out about.

Comment: @JasonEvans, I don't know if this is documented. I never read the documentation because I don't trust it. I found that out by reading the source code of ASP.NET MVC. Because when we run our application it is this source code that gets executed, not the documentation :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've [create a small class that inherit from RazorViewEngine and add profiling using MiniProfiler](https://gist.github.com/ido-ran/5676077).

This help me to see which view or partial view take the longest to render.
It does not explain why, for example due to usage of ActionLink or long calculation.